# Python Dataframe: Subract two columns if row value is -ve?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `df` with two columns `number` and `value`. I'm trying to subract two columns if value is `-ve`

df

```
            number      value
    0       5           -1
    1       6            5
    2       3            6
    3       4           -2
    4       3           -3
```

expected output

```
            number      value
    0       4           -1
    1       6            5
    2       3            6
    3       2           -2
    4       0           -3
```

Comment: you can use lamda function for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `df['number'] = df['number'].add(df['value'].clip(upper=0))`

```
In [202]: df['number'].add(df['value'].clip(upper=0))
Out[202]:
0    4
1    6
2    3
3    2
4    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `series.mask` with a condition:

```
df['number'] = df['number'].add(df['value']).mask(df['value'].gt(0),df['value'])
print(df)
```

---

```
   number  value
0       4     -1
1       5      5
2       6      6
3       2     -2
4       0     -3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
df.loc[df['value'].lt(0), 'number'] += df['value']
```

Output:

```
   number  value
0     4.0     -1
1     6.0      5
2     3.0      6
3     2.0     -2
4     0.0     -3
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "number" : [5, 6, 3, 4, 3],
    "value" : [-1, 5, 6, -2, -3]
    })
print(df)
for i in range(len(df)):
    if float(df.value[i])<0:
        df.number[i] = float(df.number[i])+float(df.value[i])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.update` with `.loc`

```
df['number'].update(df['number'] + df.loc[df2['value'] < 0, 'value'])

#output:
    number  value
0   4       -1
1   6       5
2   3       6
3   2       -2
4   0       -3
```